# How to display posts(data) of one user in recycler view?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am in the process of creating a semblance of a social network, I ran into a problem of how to display posts of one user in recycling, say in the activity "My posts", the posts themselves are already in Firebase Database.

Adding info to firebase database

```
 StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("postImage");
StorageReference imageFilePath = storageReference.child(postImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
imageFilePath.putFile(postImageUri)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                imageFilePath.getDownloadUrl()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String imageFilePath = uri.toString();
                                Post post = new Post(inputTitle.getText().toString(),
                                        currentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
                                        imageFilePath,currentUser.getUid(),
                                        currentUser.getDisplayName().toString(),inputLocation.getText().toString(),
                                        inputReasons.getText().toString(),inputDescription.getText().toString());
                                FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://enigma-41323-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/");
                                DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts").push();
                                String key = databaseReference.getKey();
                                post.setRowPostKey(key);
                                databaseReference.setValue(post)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                                getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_out_left,R.anim.anim_slide_in_left).replace(R.id.homeCont,HomeFragment.class,null).commit();
                                            }
                                        });

                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

Info to recycler view

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            postList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnap:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Post post = postSnap.getValue(Post.class);
                postList.add(post);
                adapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(),postList);
                PostRV.setAdapter(adapter);
                PostRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
                PostRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code what you have done already?

Comment: You can try to use Firebase UI library if you don't want to do anything very custom

Comment: ok so what is the problem ?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?